# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Failed connecting to MS SQL using SQL adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am trying to connect my adapter to a SQL Server 2012 Express database, but I can't quite get it right. I have downloaded a connector from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx, and added it to the `server\lib` folder in Worklight Studio.

My definitions looks as follows:

```
<dataSourceDefinition>
   <driverClass>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driverClass
   <url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=MyDB</url>
   <user>MyUser</user>
   <password>MyPassword</password>
</dataSourceDefinition>
```

The driver class seems to be right, but the URL don't. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

PS. My environment is as follows, worklight 6.1, jre7u45, windows 8, SQL Server 2012 Express.

Comment: What is the error you see in Eclipse > Views > Console > Worklight Development Server?

Comment: [ERROR   ] FWLSE0012E: ERROR: Could not connect to database. Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".). [project NewProject]

Comment: I have also tried disabling my firewall to rule that out as a source.

Comment: That's not a standard database port (that I know of, it is usually 3306 or so); are you sure about the port for the database?

Comment: Isn't 1433 standard for ms-sql?

Comment: I don't know, not sure. Don't use it myself. Verify the ports are correct at both the database and adapter XML.

Comment: I was confused in my answer. I have removed it. A SQL adapter should have no issue communicating with any SQL database; Just need to figure out the you are currently facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the connection error, see if the following will help:

- http://www.coderanch.com/t/306316/JDBC/databases/SQLServerException-TCP-IP-connection-host

  > ... open SQL Server Configuration Manager -> Protocols for SQL
  >   SQLEXPRESS, select Properties of TCP/IP. In the tab IP Addresses, set
  >   the TCPPort in section IPAll to 1433
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bd5bb6c2-a4d9-4071-b2e6-a6c83970b212/commicrosoftsqlserverjdbcsqlserverexception-the-tcpip-connection-to-the-host-has-failed?forum=sqlreportingservices

  > ... note that the JDBC URL structure is different re its use of
  >   slashes and backslashes, for example:
  >   `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS/Databases/EPS:1357

Comment: Thank you very much Idan, that solved it. You have been very helpful!

Comment: Which one of them? The settings in the SQL Server Configuration Manager or the JDBC URL?

Comment: The url. When I got in this url, it worked. `<url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=MyDb;</url>`. Though I have been in configuration manager earlier, so that might have been the case in an early phase.