# com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver not found

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, ibm-mobilefirst

**adapter.js file:**

```
var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select [sname] from [TestDb].[dbo].[studentinfo]");
function procedure1() {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,
        parameters : []
    });
}
```

**adapter.xml file:**

```
<dataSourceDefinition>
                <driverClass>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driverClass>
                <url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=TestDb</url>
                <user>user</user>
                <password>pass</password> 
            </dataSourceDefinition>
```

getting error like this:

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver not found in Worklight platform or project \/HelloWorld"
   ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the error. Your error is that the driver is missing.
Make sure you have placed the jdbc driver in your-project\server\lib

Then make sure you are correctly pointing to the database in the XML file:  [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Failed connecting to MS SQL using SQL adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654991/ibm-worklight-6-1-failed-connecting-to-ms-sql-using-sql-adapter)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it works fine now. Previously i added old version of sqljdbc.jar and now i inserted sqljdbc4.jar.

Comment: There is a checkmark icon to the left, next to the voting area. Click it.