# Connect mssql failed with mobile first SQL adapter and jdbc

Tags: jdbc, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am trying to use Mobile First SQL adapter but fail .

When i click "Run as">"Call Mobile First Adapter" on the target adapter , it gives result like:

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver not found in Worklight platform or project \/WangOnPrototype2"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

And the setting in the adapter.xml file is:

```
<dataSourceDefinition>
    <driverClass>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driverClass>
```

provided that username and password and the ip address are correct and also
sqljdbc.jar in added into the project in "Java Build Path".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not instructed to place the JDBC driver in the Java Build Path.
You are supposed to put the driver in the **server\lib** folder.

Additionally, the driver class definition is not enough.
How do you supply the database URL?

The complete setup should look like this, with your values, for example:

```
<dataSourceDefinition>
   <driverClass>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driverClass
   <url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=MyDb;</url>
   <user>MyUser</user>
   <password>MyPassword</password>
</dataSourceDefinition>
```

See here: [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Failed connecting to MS SQL using SQL adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654991/ibm-worklight-6-1-failed-connecting-to-ms-sql-using-sql-adapter)

Comment: Just want to ask one more question here ,
how can i do the same thing in other pages?
If i copy the code in index.html to others , the debuger console display:
ReferenceError: WL is not defined,
ReferenceError: WL is not defined

@Idan Adar

Comment: You read the tutorial about multi page applications in the MobileFirst developer center